# Binomial theorem incomplete expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I got this question and I am little bit confused, whether the question is correct or not.

$n\choose0$-$ n\choose1 $+$ n\choose2$-$ n\choose3$+.........+$(-1)^r$$  n\choose r$=$28$

> Now we are required to find the values of n. Its obvious that its an incomplete expression of $(1-x)^n$ but if we don't know the $r$ how can we go on to find $n$. The answer was $n=9$ but actually it would be worthless if we don't know the values where we have to stop i.e the value of $r$.

Comment: In this type of question, you are required to find both $r$ and $n$, but you only have to report the value(s) of $n$.

Comment: @StrategyThinker Is there any direct way in which I can find both the values or do I have to to use the put and check approach on the question by putting the values in the expression $(-1)^r $${ n-1}\choose{r}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,r} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,r} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  r - k \cr 
  r - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,r} \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,r} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
   - 1 \cr 
  r - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,r} \left( \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$
after which
$$
28 = 7 \cdot 4 = {{8 \cdot 7} \over {1 \cdot 2}}\quad  \to \quad \left( {n = 9,\;r = 2} \right)\; \vee \;\left( {n = 9,\;r = 6} \right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

The expression $\sum_{k=0}^{r}{n \choose k}{(-1)}^k$ can be simplified as ${(-1)}^r{n-r \choose r}$. Skipping $r=0,1$, you can see that $r$ is even and for $r \geq 4$ there is no solution, alternatively see where 28 appears in Pascal's triangle.

Comment: That's actually a type of put and check situation. Is there any way where we can get to the answer through the systematic approach.

Comment: should be ..Bin(n-1,r), if I do not mistake

Comment: @HarshSharma You could try $r=0$, simplify the expression in terms of $n$ and try solve for $n$.  Then try $r=1$, which gives a new expression in terms of $n$.  Once you do this for various values of $r$, you will notice the above formula.